# I know the big picture but can't put it in place

Tags: database

I'm interested in web development and by that I mean the bigger projects like facebook or twitter. I know the basics of java, css, php and mysql. I know there is a lot more out there. I read about it. But I don't know what the purpose is and how to put in place.

Things like: Scribe, thrift, casandra, Unix/Linux, shell/perl/python scripting, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, non-relational NoSQL datastores, JVM, nginx

I want to know why they need it, how they use it and what te purpose is.

What I need is a book like technical background of facebook for dummies or so. 
Are there any books or websites that explain this from scratch?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers! You have been very helpful. I was in the assumption, experienced programmers know almost anything about the technology there's used today. But as I read,  you can only know so much and I need to figure out which technology to use. I take on the encouragement to start building small. And will take on php and improve my skills from there.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of frameworks that do a lot of different things.  You've named a lot of different things from a lot of different areas.  The best way to think of these things is to group them by category.  Here's an example:

Suppose you have a laptop and you want to host a website.  You'll need the following at a minimum:

1) Web Server software.  Two popular options are Microsoft's IIS and Apache Web Server.

That's really all you need.  You can set up your www_root folder and load files into it.  Assuming everything is configured properly, you can now load HTML pages into that folder and access them through your IP address.  Every page you view in your web browser is in HTML format.  CSS is a stylesheet language that defines how your HTML will be formatted.  You can also start writing Javascript, as most modern browsers support the client-side scripting language.

Chances are you'll want the following as well:

2) Database software.  Two popular options are Microsoft's SQL Server and MySQL
3) Server-side scripting.  PHP is very popular, as is ASP.  You'll need the runtime deployed on your server.  Python, Ruby, Perl, etc all fall under this category.
4) Web Application Framework(s).  This will provide you with libraries for your language of choice to help develop web applications and websites.  CakePHP, Ruby on Rails, and the Google Web Toolkit are examples of web application frameworks.

Additionally, you may want to utilize:

5) Additional libraries. JQuery, for example, is quickly becoming a popular library for Javascript that handles a lot of common tasks for you.  Instead of writing complex effects code and what-not yourself, just use the pre-written code in the JQuery library.
6) Data interchange technology.  If you are passing a lot of information back and forth, you will likely want to encapsulate this data in a logical format.  Ideally, this format would describe the data and allow your applications to easily read/process it following a standard.  This is where XML and JSON come into play.

I can't recommend a good book for you to learn this stuff, but I feel that the collective replies to your question here should be more than enough to get you started.

Ultimately, what you need to do is determine what technologies you need, and then choose the right one for the job.  Don't go building an application using Ruby on Rails just because it's what Twitter used, but rather choose it because it provides some advantage to you over the other options.

Answer (score 5):

http://highscalability.com/

This is one of the best sites out there. There are several case studies describing what and why many websites use, and pointers to further references. I would also look at the Google Scalability Conference 2007 talks

http://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Scalability&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=YUg&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=v&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&ei=fl4OTPUkorIwueCQxQw&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CDIQqwQwAw

Answer (score 2):

It's all about choosing the right tool for the job in my eyes. There is so much technology out there it's impossible to learn it all. Just choose the subset that will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start is by building small simple websites, and as you come accross problems that you need solved you research the tools needed to solve those problems.

If you attack all of the areas at once, it's going to be overwhelming and you will not get anywhere.

For a general overview on what each of the technologies does, Wikipedia gives a good overview on most technologies.

If you are interested in database content which it seems like you are, a good place to start is reading up on normalisation.

Comment: Looks like I need to start typing faster :)

Answer (score 1):

> Scribe, thrift, casandra, Unix/Linux, shell/perl/python scripting, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, non-relational NoSQL datastores, JVM, nginx

Those I would search on Wikipedia for to get a quick overview. Facebook is written in PHP/MySQL. There are some books on the subject of creating social networking sites, and some books have gotten decent reviews on Amazon.com, however, I have not read any of them myself.

If I were you, I'd start with PHP/MySQL and sit down and write a simple social network. Break the project down into components and tasks and Google for each challenge you encounter such as sessions, database structure, security, friend structure, and processing POST and GET requests.

You'll learn a lot and you get the big picture. Once you see the big picture, you can take another look at different technologies that are available and then decide which component you could have developed better with other tools. I personally don't think that looking too much into the technology available is good for someone who is still in the beginning stages. Start doing, learn from it, and then your questions become much more specific and a lot of things will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is you're looking at smaller, specialty products, and not at larger, more mature technologies.  Wikipedia will actually give you a decent overview of most of the medium-and-large projects out there.

Cassandra, Hadoop, Mongo, and NoSQL are all lovely... but they're specialty tools.  SQL is a general purpose solution that works for 99% of the sites on the net.

Unix/Linux isn't a specialty tool; you might want to try going to Ubuntu's website and installing Linux, and just using it day-to-day, the way you'd use Windows.  When you need to figure out something new, like setting up a webserver, do it on the Linux box *and* a Windows box, and you'll eventually learn linux pretty darn well.

As far as scripting, O'Reilly makes a great line of books on Bash, Perl, and Python.

JVM is a Java Virtual Machine, which is a core of getting Java code to go.  Sun's website has a great set of tutorials on learning Java.

It might be much, much easier to pick a project (or three) that you'd like to learn, and learn some of these by doing.  I'd probably suggest learning some SQL before learning the newly established alternatives; that lets you learn the rest of the system, as SQL is pretty easy.  Once you've got the rest of the thing solid, try swapping in a NoSQL solution at that point.